# How to access jQuery or javascript variable inside PHP script in the same file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

My javascript file is as follows. I want to use the value variable(stores the page number(pagination)) in my php script to do database related operations.

```
<script>
    var selector = '.links';

    $(selector).on('click', function(){
        $(selector).removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        var value = $(this).text();
        window.location.href="index.php?value";
    });
</script>
```

My PHP script is

```
<?php

        $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","admin");

        if(mysqli_connect_error()) {

            die("There was an error connecting to the database");

        }

        $var = $_GET['value'];  

        $query = 'SELECT article_id, publisher, heading, date, views FROM admin LIMIT '.$var;

        $result=mysqli_query($link,$query);

        if ( false==$result ) {
          printf("error: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
        }

        echo '<div class="table-full" id="table1"><div class="table-responsive"><table class="table" data-sort="table">';
        echo '<thead><tr><th>ARTICLE</th><th>PUBLISHER</th><th>HEADING</th><th>DATE</th><th>VIEWS</th></tr></thead><tbody>';
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
              echo '<tr><td><a href="#">' ."{$row[0]} "."</a></td>
                    <td>" . " {$row[1]} </td> ".
                   "<td>" . " {$row[2]} </td> ".
                   '<td style="min-width:88px">' . " {$row[3]} </td> ".
                   "<td>" . " {$row[4]} </td></tr> ";
        }
        echo "</tbody></table></div></div>";

        mysqli_close($link);
    ?>
```

I am not very much comfortable with PHP but have a basic understanding

Thanks a lot!!! in advance to all those who tried to help me

Comment: Please provide a more detailed explanation of exactly what it is you are trying to accomplish. See [ask]

Comment: to achieve this you need to send the value to server using either `GET` or `POST` method ,depending on your requirement you can either make a form submission or make an `AJAX` request for the same..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PHP` is a server side scripting language(runes on server) whereas `javascript` is a client side scripting language (runs on browser) so you can not simply use variable/value from one to another ,but there are means to do so.

So in order to send value to variable `value` to server you need to make a request to server ,you can either make a form submission request by putting the value of `value` in a hidden field of your form so it goes to server when user submits the form or you can make an AJAX request .

**Putting value in form**

```
<input type="hidden" name="pagination_page" value="" id="pagination_page_value">
```

and then set the value of this field using jquery.

```
$("#").val(value);
```

**[AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp) Approach:**

```
$.get("savePaginationValue.php",{pagination_page_value:value}).done(function(data){
    //Success do whatever you want.
}).fail(function(){
    //Something bad happened.
});
```

and in `savePaginationValue.php` access this value easily using `$_GET["pagination_page_value"]`
you can use either `GET` or `POST` depending on your requirement .

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use javascript variable in php. However you can use php variable within javascript. Javascript is client side and php is server side, if you want to use then send with ajax because its like sending from client to server.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the proposal using Ajax you can also simply build a hidden formular(style="display:none") containing the variables you change by JavaScript and call a form submit from JavaScript to submit it to the server.

I think it's $(formName).submit();

Or if you don't have problem with showing what you send you can use GET like submission e.g. by saying   location.href="some.page.php?variablenName=someValue"