# Passing jQuery variables to external PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, google-geolocation

For my web application I am trying to post latitude and longitude variables from javascript (googleMap.js) to an external php file (closestLocations.php). I am using the AJAX post method to post the two variables across however I am still getting that the variables are undefined.

The closestLocations.php file is producing an xml file containing a list of locations in relation to a specific location (at the moment latitude and longitude are hard coded but i want to change it to these variables).

Any help would be greatly appreciated

**googleMap.js**

```
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        myPosition = {lat: latitude, lng: longitude};

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {lat:latitude,lng:longitude},
            url: "php/closestLocations.php",
            success: function(data){
                console.log(latitude);
            }
        });

        //personalise infowindow 
        infoWindow.setPosition(myPosition);
        infoWindow.setContent('You Are Here!');
        infoWindow.open(map);
        map.setCenter(myPosition);

        //display marker on map where user is located
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: myPosition,
        });

    }, function() {
        handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    });
} else {
    handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
}
```

**closestLocations.php**

```
require_once("closestLocations.php");

function parseToXML($htmlStr)
{
    $xmlStr=str_replace('<','&lt;',$htmlStr);
    $xmlStr=str_replace('>','&gt;',$xmlStr);
    $xmlStr=str_replace('"','&quot;',$xmlStr);
    $xmlStr=str_replace("'",'&#39;',$xmlStr);
    $xmlStr=str_replace("&",'&amp;',$xmlStr);
    return $xmlStr;
}

$connection=mysqli_connect ('localhost', $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
  die('Not connected : ' . mysqli_error());
}

// Set the active MySQL database
$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($connection, $database);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysqli_error());
}

$query = "SELECT locationName, address, town, postcode, telephone, ( 3959 * acos ( cos ( radians(50.6346) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-6.6169) ) + sin ( radians(50.6346) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM defibrillators HAVING distance < 5 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 10 ";
$result=mysqli_query($connection, $query);
if(!$result){
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error());
} 

header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Start XML file, echo parent node
echo "<?xml version='1.0' ?>";
echo '<markers>';
$ind=0;
// Iterate through the rows, printing XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  // Add to XML document node
  echo '<marker ';
  echo 'name="' . parseToXML($row['locationName']) . '" ';
  echo 'address="' . parseToXML($row['address']) . '" ';
  echo 'town="' . parseToXML($row['town']) . '" ';
  echo 'postcode="' . parseToXML($row['postcode']) . '" ';
  echo 'telephone="' . parseToXML($row['telephone']) . '" ';
  echo '/>';
  $ind = $ind + 1;
}

// End XML file
echo '</markers>';
```

Comment: Check this similar thread :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44607232/how-to-access-jquery-or-javascript-variable-inside-php-script-in-the-same-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access jQuery or javascript variable inside PHP script in the same file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44607232/how-to-access-jquery-or-javascript-variable-inside-php-script-in-the-same-file)

Comment: Where in closestLocations do you attempt to access the posted variables?

Comment: Sorry i thought i had this included, above function parseToXML i have $lat = $_POST['lat']; $lng = $_POST['lng'];

Answer (score 0):

Your JS ajax call is requesting PHP file via POST method, so the variables you post in data will be avaiable in PHP script in $_POST superglobal.

```
var_dump($_POST); // array(2) { ["lat"]=> string(1) "1" ["lng"]=> string(1) "2" }
```

so latitude can be accessed via $_POST['lat']; and longitude via $_POST['lng']